# Неверный расчет количества элементов в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача подсчитать количество элементов в списке.
Но расчет происходит неверно, имен Mary с списке 3, а выводит в консоли 4

```
# Пример работы со списком
# Поиск конкретных данных по списку (Например для группировки имен)
contacts_list = ['Any', 'Mary', 'Jany', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'John', 'Ted', 'Mary']
print('В массиве находится ' + str(len(contacts_list)), 'имен' )
if 'Mary' in contacts_list:
    print('Имя Mary есть в списке.', 'В списке находится '+ str(len('Mary')), 'имени Mary')
```

Comment: `len` - длина строки, соответственно в слове `Mary` 4 буквы, что и выводится. Для количества элементов в списке используется `contacts_list.count('Mary')`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: или можно попробовать при помощи модуля `collections` [`collections.Counter(['Any', 'Mary', 'Jany', 'Fred', 'Mary', 'John', 'Ted', 'Mary']);
print(a["Mary"])`](https://repl.it/repls/LiveWaterloggedCamel)